# Case-folding a string in LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, unicode, lua

I would like to perform [Unicode case-folding](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/ch05.pdf#page=43) in the Lua interpreter of LuaTeX running within the TeX Live ecosystem.

Can you suggest whether there is an existing implementation available
in TeX Live, or whether I should implement the case-folding algorithm
myself using the `UnicodeData.txt` and `CaseFolding.txt` files provided as a part
of [the unicode-data package](https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-data) in TeX Live?

---

Side note: LaTeX3 implements case-folding as TeX commands, see
function `\str_casefold:n` in [LaTeX3 interfaces](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#page=142). I would find it
somewhat amusing if it were easier to case-fold a string in TeX than
it would be in Lua. Is it?

EDIT: I updated the question to make it clear that I am looking for a Lua implementation of Unicode case-folding, not a TeX (or LaTeX3) implementation.

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/lua-uni-algos

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: In general, yes. In my use case, I need to case-fold a programmatic string in Lua. TeX will never see this string.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thank you, this seems to be the answer to my problem. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lua-uni-algos package https://ctan.org/pkg/lua-uni-algos contains an implementation.